# XMLHttpRequest error calling Parse.com app from Trigger.io app

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, trigger.io

I've got a Trigger.io app that queries a Parse.com app for some content in a Parse class called "Event". When I run the query (after the page loads), I receive the following error in the Trigger.io Toolkit console (generated from my javascript below):

```
Error: 100 XMLHttpRequest failed: {"readyState":4,"onloadstart":null,"withCredentials":false,"onerror":null,"onabort":null,"status":0,"responseXML":null,"onload":null,"onprogress":null,"upload":{"onloadstart":null,"onabort":null,"onerror":null,"onload":null,"onprogress":null},"statusText":"","responseText":""}'
```

Here is the javascript (in js/index.js):

```
// Set up for query
var Event = Parse.Object.extend("Event");   
var query = new Parse.Query(Event);
query.limit(3);

// Make the query
query.find({
  success: function(results) {
    forge.logging.log("[getEvents] Successfully retrieved " + results.length + " events.");
    // Do something with the returned Parse.Object values
  },
  error: function(error) {
    forge.logging.log("[getEvents] Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
  }
});
```

And here is the markup that calls the javascript (placed at the end of the page):

```
<script>
Parse.initialize("MyParseComApplicationID", "MyParseComJavascriptAPIKey");
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
```

I've tried lots of variations on this, but I've not been able to get past this (and I haven't seen this error here on stackoverflow or in lots of google searching).

Any thoughts are appreciated. Thanks

**UPDATE**: Just to clarify, the problem occurs when trying to run the app from Forge on an Android device. When I run from Forge on Web (e.g. just in a browser), I do not receive the error and I **do** receive data back from Parse.com.

I've tried with both the Javascript Key and the Client Key.

Comment: I switched from .find to .get and I still have a problem. It seems that calling Parse.Initialize is failing. It works for Web but not for Android. Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: I'm feeling pretty stupid now - I think this is a cross-domain issue. If so, I'll need to call a function on my own server, which would then call Parse. If that's correct, it makes the idea of Cloud Code seem pretty useless for Javascript / HTML5 apps (but still useful for native apps).

Answer (score 0):

After receiving some guidance from Antoine and re-reading the photo demo (https://github.com/blueski/Forge-Parse-Demo/blob/master/js/parse-demo.js), I realized that I did not need to call Parse.initialize at all and instead I could use forge.request.ajax to get around the cross domain limitation.

One important item that eluded me was to use the Parse.com REST Key, not the Javascript Key when calling with forge.request.ajax

Also (really embarrassed here), it's always a good idea to confirm that wifi is actually enabled! :)